# How to use Concat on WhereIn clause in postgress

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's say I have this data on my table:

```
[
  {
    name: "test1",
    address: "hello",
    value: "hi1"
  },
  {
    name: "test2",
    address: "hello2",
    value: "hi2"
  },
  {
    name: "test3",
    address: "hello2",
    value: "hi3"
  },
  {
    name: "test4",
    address: "hello",
    value: "hi4"
  },
]
```

I have a `wherein` function where I need to select the item with name (`test1` AND address `hello`) AND (name `test2` address `hello2`).

So what I did to achieve this is by concat.

```
select concat(name, '-', address) as a, name, address from tableName
where a in ("test1-hello", "test2-hello2")
```

This works ok in mysql, but in postgress you can't use alias on where so I tried:

```
select concat(name, '-', address) as a, name, address from tableName
where concat(name, '-', address) in ("test1-hello", "test2-hello2")
```

The code above gives me a syntax error. Any ideas how to achieve this?

---

**UPDATE**:

I found an answer to my problem as per @jarlh's comment where I don't need to use concat and just do:

```
where (name, address) in (('test1', 'hello'), ('test2', 'hello2'))
```

instead. However I will leave the issue open as there might be someone willing to answer on how to use concat on where clause.

Comment: @jarlh yes that would be the fitting answer on my problem. Thanks!

Comment: Using concat in the where clause will probably ruin the optimization. Also, such comparisons are a bit dangerous, since `concat('A-B', '-', 'C')` = `concat('A', '-', 'B-C')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"test1-hello"` is read as an *identifier*, i.e. here as a column name. Use single quotes instead to write string literals.

However, I'd do it as:

```
where (name, address) in (('test1', 'hello'), ('test2', 'hello2'))
```